# How to make an image disappear using libgdx

Tags: android, mobile, libgdx

I have been making a game and lately i have had a problem of making an image disappear. My code is as follows

```
package com.me.fixGame;

import java.util.Random;









import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;


import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Scaling;
import com.sun.jmx.snmp.tasks.Task;


public class fixGame implements ApplicationListener {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture trash; 
    Texture paper;
    SpriteBatch spritebatch;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 pas;
    boolean collide;
    boolean countMe=false;
    Vector2 size;
    Vector2 size2;
    Vector2 pos;
    Rectangle bounds;
    Rectangle bounds2;
    float delay = 1; // seconds
boolean counted= false;
    int score = 3;
    //Texture Gogreen;
    String myScore;
    Texture background; 
    CharSequence str = "Lives left: 3"; // = myScore;
    CharSequence line = "Score: 0"; // = myScore;
    String myLife;
    int life=0;
    BitmapFont font;
    float x;
    float y;
    boolean collision = false;
    @Override
    public void create() {  

     //Gogreen = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/gogreenNow.jpg"));
     background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));

     x= background.getWidth();
     y=background.getHeight();
        //float delaySeconds = 1;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    trash = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));
    paper = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/paper1.jpg"));
    position = new Vector2(100, 50);
    pos = new Vector2(54, 14);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();

    size2 = new Vector2(trash.getWidth() ,trash.getHeight() );
    //size2.y = trash.getHeight();
    //size2.x = trash.getWidth();
    size = new Vector2(paper.getWidth() ,paper.getHeight());

    bounds= new Rectangle(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
    bounds2= new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
    public void update(){
        bounds.set(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
        bounds2.set(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);

        position.x = position.x -2- Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
    }




    @Override
    public void render() {

        if(bounds.overlaps(bounds2)){
            collision=true; 
            counted=true;
        }else{
            collision=false;
        }

        if(collision==true){

        } 
        if(pos.y<640){
            counted=false;
        } else if(pos.y > 640 && collision==false && counted==false){
            counted=true;
            score= score-1;
            myScore = "Lives left: " + score;
            str = myScore;
        }



        if(bounds.overlaps(bounds2)){

            countMe=true;
            life= life+50;
            myLife = "Score: " + life;
            line = myLife;
        }


        if(position.x<0){
            position.x= position.x+11;
        }
        if(position.x>425){
            position.x= position.x-11;
        }


          update();
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        pos.y=pos.y-12;
        if(pos.y<0){
            pos.y = 700;
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
              pos.x = randomGenerator.nextInt(500);
        }
        BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();


        batch.begin();

         batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());


        batch.draw(paper, pos.x, pos.y);
        batch.draw(trash, position.x, position.y);
        font.setScale(3);

        font.setColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f);
        font.draw(batch, str, 200,900);
        font.draw(batch, line, 200, 700);
                batch.end();
                font.dispose(); 
    }

     @Override  
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

I want to make my image called paper to disappear which I instantiate here.

```
 x= background.getWidth();
     y=background.getHeight();
        //float delaySeconds = 1;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    trash = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));
    paper = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/paper1.jpg"));
    position = new Vector2(100, 50);
    pos = new Vector2(54, 14);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
```

And where i want it to disappear is below:

if(bounds.overlaps(bounds2)){

```
        countMe=true;
        life= life+50;
        myLife = "Score: " + life;
        line = myLife;
    }
```

What i want to do is when the two objects overlap(bounds and bounds2) the score should be changed and one of the objects, the paper, should hide. How do i make an image hide?

Comment: Simply don't draw it, put an 'if' statement around it and check if it's colliding.

Comment: i already checked if it is colliding on my last piece of code but how can you make not draw an image but still make it appear. What i am trying to do is i have an image that is already drawn on the screen and then once the other image collides it dissapears, how can i not draw it?

Comment: in other words, how do i stop redrawing an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becuase you already are setting the collision state to a variable, in the render() method you just need to wrap the batch.draw() method. I've tested this code and it works. You also need to set collision to false when you set the paper back to the top, I'm guessing you want it to hide completely until it resets. Please note I've also made some small tweaks just so it's easier to test. If there are still runtime bugs it's not related to this change.

```
@Override
public void render() {
    if (bounds.overlaps(bounds2)) {
        collision = true;
        counted = true;
    }

    if (pos.y < 640) {
        counted = false;
    } else if (pos.y > 640 && collision == false && counted == false) {
        counted = true;
        score = score - 1;
        myScore = "Lives left: " + score;
        str = myScore;
    }

    if (bounds.overlaps(bounds2)) {
        countMe = true;
        life = life + 50;
        myLife = "Score: " + life;
        line = myLife;
    }

    if (position.x < 0) {
        position.x = position.x + 11;
    }
    if (position.x > 425) {
        position.x = position.x - 11;
    }

    update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    pos.y = pos.y - 2;
    if (pos.y < 0) {
        pos.y = 700;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        pos.x = 250;
        collision = false;
    }
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();

    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    if (!collision) {
    batch.draw(paper, pos.x, pos.y);
    }
    batch.draw(trash, position.x, position.y);
    font.setScale(1.5f);

    font.setColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    font.draw(batch, str, 20, 50);
    font.draw(batch, line, 20, 100);
    batch.end();
    font.dispose();
}
```

Comment: There is a run-time error, the image just is white, the whole time. Is there any other way to stop redrawing the image? Or is there a solution to the problem i am getting when use your code?

Comment: Actually your answer is edit i will try this  new code

Comment: Thanks for the help, but can you tell me what edits you made?

Comment: I moved the "collision = false", I added the if statement around batch.draw(paper...) and I set pos.x to 250 (just to test, you can change back back to a random value).